# How can I remove an Implicit Share in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Was wondering if anyone could offer some insight to how I would remove an Implicit Share in CRM 2011... The situation goes like this: I have a custom entity that can get nested under other entities of the same type. The parent entity is owned by Team A. The child is owned by Team B. Users who are members of Team A can see the entity owned by Team B because of the Relationship Behaviors (parental) that were set up...

This behavior was giving us a big headache because we were trying to control visibility of that record by team ownership. We finally pinned it to the Relationship Behaviors setting. We set that for Referential, and the problem has gone away for any new child entities we create, but not for the ones that are already there. I'm looking to remove this implicit share without having to remove/recreate the affected entities as that would take some time due to the number of them there.

Just looking for a different angle on this, or some ideas/direction on how to easily remove these relationships.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I found... We can either zero out the relationship in the POA, or we can recreate the records... We tried reimporting the records from a development org we have, but the problem persisted since we are using clones (same guids)... We have to reimport to the dev org with new guids, and then can promote to test org using clones at that point...